# Discord Bot Python - Send message to specific channel

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

Im trying to create that bot that will send a message to a specific channel upon command (!ping channelid message)

```
async def ping(message, canal, role):
    if message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        await message.channel.purge(limit=1) 

        channel = client.get_channel(f'{canal}')
        await channel.send(f'{role}')


client.run(token)
```

Somehow, i cant make it work. If i print the variable canal i get the channel id, however when executing the command i always get discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

What im I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it's the same with `.js` without using any of these three `var, let, const` then your variable will be `any`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67391603/discord-py-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-send)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the f strings. and set canal to only accept ints. so `canal: int` or you can do `channel = client.get_channel(int(canal))` According to your error you are never actually retrieving the channel.

Comment: used the channel = client.get_channel(int(canal)) and worked.